# Showing the data of the right side of the TimeLine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I show the description Data on the left or the right side of the timeline acording of it Candidate.Saving result?
If it's `Candidate.Saving == true` it should be on the left, if it's `Candidate.Saving==false` it should be on the right side of the time line.
I will shou here my candidate Model And my View.

```
public class Candidate : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Saving { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate

@{
 ViewData["Title"] = "CandidateHistory";
}

<h2>Canidate - @Model.Name</h2>

<label>History</label>
<hr />

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
</div>

@foreach (var Description in Model.Description)
{
    @if (Model.Saving == true)
    {
        <ul>
            <li class="timeline">
                <div class="timeline-badge">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                        <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                        <p>
                            <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-body">
                        <p>@Model.Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    }
    @if (Model.Saving == false)
    {

            <ul>
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>@Model.Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            }

            }
</div>

            @*<div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="timeline">
                            <li>
                                  <li class="timeline-inverted">
                                Isto é para inverter o lado
                                <div class="timeline-badge">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline-panel">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                                        <p>
                                            <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p>@Model.Description</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>*@



            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@Model.Saving"> Add History Description</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form asp-action="CandidateHistory">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Selects</label>
                                    <select asp-for="Saving" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="false">Candidate </option>
                                        <option value="true">Hitachi</option>s
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group"></label>
                                    <input asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**What I've tried to do:**
I have tried to make a foreach method where the side depends of the Candidate.Saving, But the result was this:

[image]

**I have managed to fix it.
This is how I did It:**

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    @if (Model.Saving == true)
    {
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li class="timeline">
            <div class="timeline-badge">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
  @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>@Model.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 }
    @if (Model.Saving == false)
{
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-badge">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>@Model.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
}
    </div>
</div>
```

> **I only have on doubt right now,** to be able to add more than one Description for the candidate I should Create a list off Descriptions
>   and do a foreach method in the view right?

Right now my controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult CandidateHistory(int Id)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(Id)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (candidate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Candidate candidates = new Candidate();
            candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidate);
            candidates.DescriptionList.Add(new Candidate { Description = candidate.Description });
            candidates.DescriptionList.Add(new Candidate { Title = candidate.Title });
            candidates.DescriptionList.Add(new Candidate { DateOfDescription = candidate.DateOfDescription });
            candidates.DescriptionList.Add(new Candidate { Saving = candidate.Saving });
            applicationcontext.Candidates.Add(candidates);
            return View();
        }
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateHistory")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CandidateHistoryPost(int? id, Candidate candidatelist)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        using (var context = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidateUpdate = await context.Candidates.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Candidate>(candidateUpdate, "", s => s.Description, s => s.Title, s => s.DateOfDescription, s => s.Saving))
            {
                try
                {
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(CandidateHistory));
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                        "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                        "see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
            return View(candidateUpdate);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to output an Candidate.DescriptionList to the CandidateHistory View so that way I can save into that list all the descriptions, description title, date and "saving", so i can do a foreach method to output all the description of that user.
But now I have this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate.DescriptionList.get returned null.`

Comment: If you’ve managed to fix it, you should post an answer detailing your fix, then accept that answer.

Comment: @ColeJohnson it's not fully fixed I stil need to do a foreach method to output all the descriptions not only one

Comment: @ColeJohnson can you please check out the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it.
This is how I did It:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    @if (Model.Saving == true)
    {
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li class="timeline">
            <div class="timeline-badge">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
  @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>@Model.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
 }
    @if (Model.Saving == false)
{
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-badge">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>@Model.Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
}
    </div>
</div>
```

> **I only have on doubt right now,** to be able to add more than one Description for the candidate I should Create a list off Descriptions
>   and do a foreach method in the view right?