# DbUpdateException "Unable to save changes"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to save multiple descriptions of a candidate, And foreach one show them in the Description View accordingly.

**Here is my Controller:**

```
public IActionResult CandidateHistory(int Id)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidate = 
  applicationcontext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => 
         q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);
            if (candidate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            applicationcontext.Candidates.Add(candidate);

            return View(candidate);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateHistory")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CandidateHistoryPost([Bind("Description, Title, 
     DateOfDescription, Saving")]Candidate candidate, int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
                {
                    var candidates = 
        applicationContext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => 
           q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);
                    //candidates.Description = candidate.Description;
                    //candidates.Saving = candidate.Saving;
                    //candidates.Title = candidate.Title;
                    //candidates.DateOfDescription = 
              candidate.DateOfDescription;
                    //candidate.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);


                    var guardar = candidate;
                    candidates.Saving = guardar.Saving;
                    candidates.Title = guardar.Title;
                    candidates.Description = guardar.Description;
                    candidates.DateOfDescription = guardar.DateOfDescription;




                    candidate = candidates;
                    candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidate);
                    candidate.DescriptionList = candidates.DescriptionList;
                    applicationContext.Candidates.Add(candidate);
                    applicationContext.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("CandidateHistory");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                "see your system administrator.");
        }

        return View(candidate);
    }
```

**And Also here is my Model of the Candidate:**

```
 public class Candidate : BaseEntity
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Saving { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> DescriptionList { get; set; }
    public Candidate()
    {
        DescriptionList = new List<Candidate>();
    }

 }
```

**And here is my View:**

```
 @model HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate

  @{
 ViewData["Title"] = "CandidateHistory";
 }

 <h2>Canidate - @Model.Name</h2>

  <label>History</label>
 <hr />

  <div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
    @foreach (var Description in Model.DescriptionList)
    {
        @if (Model.Saving == true)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">@Model.Title</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa- 
  clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>@Model.Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        @if (Model.Saving == false)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa- 
  clock-o"></i> @Model.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>@Model.Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        }
   </div>
  </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
   target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@Model.Saving"> Add History 
      Description</button>
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
  aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-action="CandidateHistory">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"> 
  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"> 
           </span>
                 </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"> 
                 </label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text- 
              danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Selects</label>
                    <select asp-for="Saving" class="form-control">
                        <option value="false">Candidate </option>
                        <option value="true">Hitachi</option>s
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group" > 
           </label>
                    <input asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn- 
       default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
     dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

The Catch methos is throwing an exception, and I do not understand why.

```
   catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
```

The exception is :

> {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Candidates' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>      at HCCBPOHR.Web.Controllers.HomeController.CandidateHistoryPost(Candidate candidate, Int32 Id) in C:\Users\137258\Documents\hccbpohr\src\Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 628}

Comment: Please uncomment `ex` and provide the `DbUpdateException` details.

Comment: Having a look at what the exception is actually telling you would be a good starting point. Would also help us help you if it is still not letting you sort the problem out.

Comment: @PaulF I can't get the DbUpdateException, it doesnt have any value

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve and what is the logic behind of your code?

Comment: Well if you are getting an exception thrown that is caught by that catch statement - there will be information in the DbUpdateException.

Comment: @octavioccl I'm trying to save into a list all the Descriptions, so I can show all of them in a TimeLine( into the right side according to the Candidate.Saving)

Comment: The exception explains what is going on _"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Candidates' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."_

Comment: @PaulF and how can I fix this?

Comment: @DorinMunteanu, let me see if I understand your problem, The idea is add a new candidate you are entering in your form as a new element in the DescriptionList of the canditate you pass initially to your view?

Comment: See this search of SO specifically for the exception message there may be some useful suggestions : https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net+Cannot+insert+explicit+value+for+identity+column+in+table+when+IDENTITY_INSERT+is+set+to+OFF+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5suzApoPcAhUCSsAKHW9hClwQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1920&bih=1024

Comment: @octavioccl The idea is adding a new `Candidate.Description`,`Candidate.Title`,`Candidate.Saving`,`Candidate.DateOfDescription` into `DescriptionList` none of those values were passed into the view initially

Comment: Possibly this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016306/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-clientdetails-when-i

Comment: @PaulF Maybe what I did on my controller is wrong, can you check it out please?

Comment: @DorinMunteanu: Unfortunately I am finishing now till tomorrow

Comment: @PaulF please check this Out tomorrow, Also my oher thread could help you understand what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133711/showing-the-data-of-the-right-side-of-the-timeline

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the exception, it says that `An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Candidates' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

This means that in the SQL, you cannot insert in the table the value of the primary key as you have set it to identity key (for e.g. `IDENTITY(1,1)`). Most probably, the key will be ID in your case. In c# code, add an attribute over the field in the model class.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I have added that attribute to the model class and still get the same exception

Comment: Can you please share your sql structure and entity framework mapping?